# Racket/Scheme : how to construct a query with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm stuck on this problem, searching a clean way to build this query.

Basically, I'm willing to run an update on some fields of a table, however the exact fields will be dynamic, and determined by the arguments passed to the function.

```
(define
  (update-user user-id
               #:first-name [first-name #f]
               #:last-name [last-name #f])
    (query-exec
     dbc
     (string-append
      "UPDATE user"
      (if first-name
      "SET first_name = ?"
      ""
      )
      (if last-name
      "SET last_name = ?"
      ""
      )
      "WHERE identifier = ?")

     ; ?? how to pass dynamically the arguments ?

      user-id
     ))
```

So, the update should run on first_name only if the parameter is provided, same with last name. I can build the query itself, however I don't know how to pass (or not !) the arguments after that.

Or maybe the query should be built a completely different way ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I've only tried this with a mock-up version of `query-exec`* so you might have to do some slight changes:

You should be able to do this with a mix of `apply`, `list*`:

```scm
(define (build-query con pre verb post lst)
  (let ((key (car lst)))
    (let loop ((lst (cdr lst)) (sql "") (parms '()))
      (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))
          (list* con (string-append pre " " sql " "  post) (reverse (cons key parms)))
          (let ((field (car lst)) (val (cadr lst)))
            (loop 
             (cddr lst) 
             (string-append sql (format "~a ~a=?" (if (null? parms) verb ",") field))
             (cons val parms)))))))
```

then

```
(apply query-exec (build-query con "UPDATE user" "SET" "WHERE identifier=?" '("123456" "first_name" "Patrick")))
=> (query-exec con "UPDATE user SET first_name=? WHERE identifier=?" "Patrick" "123456")
```

and

```
(apply query-exec (build-query con "UPDATE user" "SET" "WHERE identifier=?" '("123456" "first_name" "Patrick" "last-name" "Useldinger")))
=> (query-exec con "UPDATE user SET first_name=?, last-name=? WHERE identifier=?" "Patrick" "Useldinger" "123456")
```